# Polars groupby_dynamic with grouping on non-date column too

Tags: python, python-polars

I've got a polars DataFrame that I am wanting to calculate a 5 year smooth moving average on. However, I don't want to just `groupby_dynamic` on the year column, but I have a geographical unit, that I am wanting to `groupby` on as well.

For example:

```
┌────────────┬─────────┬──────────┬────────────────────────────┬─────┬────────────┬────────────────────────────┬────────────────┬───────────┐
│ year       ┆ state   ┆ district ┆ candidate                  ┆ ... ┆ totalvotes ┆ Candidate_Name             ┆ State_District ┆ Last_Name │
│ ---        ┆ ---     ┆ ---      ┆ ---                        ┆     ┆ ---        ┆ ---                        ┆ ---            ┆ ---       │
│ date       ┆ str     ┆ i64      ┆ str                        ┆     ┆ i64        ┆ str                        ┆ str            ┆ str       │
╞════════════╪═════════╪══════════╪════════════════════════════╪═════╪════════════╪════════════════════════════╪════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 1976-01-01 ┆ alabama ┆ 1        ┆ BILL DAVENPORT             ┆ ... ┆ 157170     ┆ bill davenport             ┆ alabama-1      ┆ davenport │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1976-01-01 ┆ alabama ┆ 1        ┆ JACK EDWARDS               ┆ ... ┆ 157170     ┆ jack edwards               ┆ alabama-1      ┆ edwards   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1976-01-01 ┆ alabama ┆ 1        ┆ WRITEIN                    ┆ ... ┆ 157170     ┆ writein                    ┆ alabama-1      ┆ writein   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1976-01-01 ┆ alabama ┆ 2        ┆ J CAROLE KEAHEY            ┆ ... ┆ 156362     ┆ j carole keahey            ┆ alabama-2      ┆ keahey    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 1976-01-01 ┆ alabama ┆ 2        ┆ WILLIAM L "BILL" DICKINSON ┆ ... ┆ 156362     ┆ william l "bill" dickinson ┆ alabama-2      ┆ dickinson │
```

Specifically, with this example, I want to `groupby` year and calculate the 5 year smooth moving average for the particular `State_District`.

What would be the most efficient way to do this?

I've tried:

```
mapped = election_lab.filter(
    pl.col("party") == "DEMOCRAT"
).groupby_dynamic(
    ["year", "State_District"], every = "5y"
).agg(
    pl.apply(exprs = ["candidatevotes", "totalvotes"], f = lambda x: x[0]/x[1]).alias("Dem_Vote_Share")
)
```

This one understandably indicated that I couldn't pass a list to `groupby_dyanmic`. So I thought I might do them in stages.

So I tried:

```
mapped = election_lab.filter(
    pl.col("party") == "DEMOCRAT"
).groupby(
    ["year", "State_District"]
).agg(
    pl.apply(exprs = ["candidatevotes", "totalvotes"], f = lambda x: x[0]/x[1]).alias("Dem_Vote_Share")
)

mapped_dynamic = mapped.groupby_dynamic(
    "year", every = "5y"    
).agg(
    pl.avg("Dem_Vote_Share").alias("SMA")
)
```

But this doesn't do what I'd want exactly either... and just returned a column of all `null`.

Comment: Groupby dynamic (https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/dataframe/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby_dynamic.html) has a `by` argument for grouping on the non-date column, did you try that?